# Difference of merging from master branch and from dev branch

Tags: git, merge

Assume that I've got a project with two branches. One is master and the other is dev. I'm using git and do either of the following:

### Case 1

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

### Case 2

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

My question: What is the difference of case 1 and case 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

Will checkout the 'master' branch and merge from the 'dev' branch. Any applicable changes within 'dev' will be in 'master' once this command has completed.

```
git checkout dev
git merge master
```

Will checkout the 'dev' branch and merge from the 'master' branch. Any applicable changes within 'master' will be in 'dev' once this command has completed.

For more information, take a look at [Basic Branching and Merging](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Comment: So there is no difference in how the merge happens, i.e. what happens to the version controlled files?

Comment: The actual process is indentical, you are just selecting destination/source. I added a link to my post that explains it some more.

Comment: Thanks. It is the obvious I have trouble in comprehending.

Answer (score 5):

in the first case, the changes made in dev are merged to master (leaving dev unaffected)....whereas in the second case, the changes made in master (leaving master unaffected) are merged to dev. Please check [this link](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for more details.